# How do I implement 2 python range functions at the same time?

Tags: python, range

I have a statement which is working fine.

```
 for i in range(1, 4):
    piece = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[1]/li[{}]/div/div[2]/p'.format(i))
    piece.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.back()
```

After it gets finished with this loop I want to run it again but with /ul[2]. and then /ul[3] and so on...

...//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[2]/...
...//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[3]/...

I can't get the coding for two ranges in the same sentence. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried nesting a for loop inside your current one?

Comment: If your questions are answered, accept/upvote them to recognise people's efforts to help you. This is how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `for` loop.

```py
x = 10 # How many times do you want to loop over /ul[INDEX]

# Outer loop
for j in range(1, x):

    # Inner loop
    for i in range(1, 4):
        piece = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[{}]/li[{}]/div/div[2]/p'.format(j, i))
        piece.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.back()
```

Comment: I would agree a nested for loop, is the simplest solution for this question.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Stack overflow community are full of geniuses.

Comment: @dave, try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath
(f'//*[@id="js_proList"]/ul[1 <= position() and position() < {x}]/li[1 <= position() and position() < 4]/div/div[2]/p')` and check output.

Comment: @dave if you found the answer useful / correct, then click the upvote &/ checkmark button on the left of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

nested loops of implementation is accurate , you can also try updating xpath dynamically once one iteration is done.